# Как правильно загрузить изображение на сервер?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, reactjs

Пишу админ панель для сайта, туда нужно загружать изображения. 
Локально все работает, изображения загружаются в определенную папку, в базу (MySql) заносится их путь.
Но при загрузке на хостинг появляется долгий pending - 20 секунд и в консоли появляется ошибка - `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.
Как вообще правильно загружать изображения на сервер если возможно, что изображения будут довольно большими?

Я делаю это так:

php:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/'; 
$full_path = $path.$_FILES['image']["name"]; 
...вставка записи в бд...
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']["tmp_name"], $full_path);
```

js (ReactJS):

```
formData.append("image", *файл из инпута*);
axios.post('http://***.php', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, определитесь, проблема (ошибка) MySQL, JavaScript или PHP (судя по тому, что я вижу - не MySQL). Если так - то решайте ЭТУ проблему безотносительно к БД. PS. Сперва загрузите файл, переместите его куда надо с каким надо именем, и только потом пишите в БД.

Comment: @Akina Локально все работает, проблема наблюдается только при загрузке на хостинг. Происходит запрос к php файлу, который завершается с ошибкой. При этом путь к php файлу правильный, я вижу что он слишком долго обрабатывается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена использованием относительного пути к папке.

Было:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/';
```

Стало:

```
$path = '../img/';
```